# Have Problem with Adobe Flash import library filesystem.file

Tags: filesystems, flash-cs5, importerror

When i code my program, i need to use filesystem.file to be imported in my action script.

But when i import that, Adobe Flash Professional CS5 did'nt know the library.

Could anybody know about it.. or i must downloaded the new version or maybe only package?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the filesystem package is for AIR only....

You got AIR installed?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your project to be an AIR application

Comment: Please expand this answer and explain *why*

Answer (score 0):

if u created as library project ,you should set manually ,select project-->properties -->Flex library compiler-->check the 'Include Adobe AIR Libraries'.